# get numeric values from an ENUM column's issue

Tags: mysql

to get numeric values from an ENUM column, can be using

```
mysql> SELECT enum_col+0 FROM tbl_name;
```

[reference here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html)

But in my mysql5.5 console,this query return:

```
1.0000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want to get the a integer number `1`

I know I can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(enum_col,UNSIGNED) FROM tbl_name;
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(enum_col AS UNSIGNED) FROM tbl_name;
```

I want to know why `enum_col+0` return a float,

and any other way to get numeric values from an ENUM column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article - [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html); it describes how MySQL does conversion between different types; there are some rules, in your case you get result as a floating-point value.

...and try another variant:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM TRIM(LEADING 'enum' FROM column_type))) INTO @enum
  FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'enum_col';

SELECT FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT('''', enum_col, ''''), @enum) FROM tbl_name
```

or this one:

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM TRIM(LEADING 'enum' FROM column_type))), '''', '') INTO @enum
  FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'enum_col';

SELECT FIND_IN_SET(enum_col, @enum) FROM tbl_name
```